# SQL drop a column that was created during the same transaction?

Tags: mysql, eloquent, transactions

I'm using a transaction to make alterations to my database, this way if anything fails during the alterations i can roll back without any harm having been done.

However, since i run my queries based on a list of queries that puts my database in it's final state (any time i need to make changes, i simply add a new rule to the list), it fails when i try to drop a column that was added during the same transaction.

Example:

```
START TRANSACTION;
    ALTER TABLE "servers" ADD COLUMN "test" INTEGER NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE "servers" DROP COLUMN "test";
COMMIT;
```

When I run this, i get something along the lines of

```
column "test" in the middle of being added, try again later
```

I understand why this is happening, since the transaction hasn't been committed yet the column doesn't exist to be dropped. However is there a way around this specifically so that I can drop the column in the same transaction? Or at least queue it to be deleted once the transaction is committed.

I feel it worth noting that the queries being run within the transaction are generated using Eloquent ORM Blueprints.

Comment: Does adding default change anything `ALTER TABLE servers ADD test INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;`?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda no, that doesn't make a difference nor do i see why it would.

Comment: Because adding a column to a table with NOT NULL that has data already will fail. It doesn't change anything related to transaction

Comment: How about if you use two transactions? One where you add the field and use it. Then another where you drop the field? You can even set a `@variable` to check in the second transaction like `@success`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support table changes in transactions. From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cannot-roll-back.html):

> Some statements cannot be rolled back. In general, these include data definition language (DDL) statements, such as those that create or drop databases, those that create, drop, or alter tables or stored routines.